# Is there any solutions for implicit intent is not working with some devices

Tags: android, webview

Android Activity having webview, If the url matches with upi:// then the intent chooser should popup its working with all the devices but some devices like mi with android 9  is not working properly

if (url.startsWith("upi://")) {
this if checks the url starts with upi:// or not if its starts with upi the chooser popups all apps whose package names are start with upi. Its working with all devices

```
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);


            if (url.startsWith("upi://")) {
                Toast.makeText(home.this, url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                webView.stopLoading();
                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Pay with...");
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                        startActivityForResult(chooser, 1, null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(home.this, "ELSE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {


                    String MakeShortText = "PhonePe have not been installed";

                    Toast.makeText(home.this, MakeShortText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

    });





}
```

logs

```
2019-10-27 18:55:15.781 17960-17960/? E/ChooserActivityInjector: getResolversForIntent [boolean, boolean, interface java.util.List]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: getResolversForIntent [boolean, boolean, interface java.util.List]
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2068)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2047)
    at com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivityInjector.createSortedResloveListByResolverController(ChooserActivityInjector.java:91)
    at com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivityInjector.startInterceptByMiAppStore(ChooserActivityInjector.java:66)
    at com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity.onCreate(ResolverActivity.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity.onCreate(ChooserActivity.java:274)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

Comment: What does "not working properly" mean? What are your exact symptoms? I would expect your app to crash on any device that lacks an activity that supports `ACTION_VIEW` for that URL. And, since `ACTION_VIEW` is not designed to support `startActivityForResult()`, your `onActivityResult()` callback method (if you have one) is unlikely to get anything useful. I recommend that you switch to `startActivity()` and wrap it in a `try`/`catch` block to handle `ActivityNotFoundException`.

Comment: I Explained my question please check it once @ CommonsWare

Comment: "I Explained my question" -- if anything, you made it more confusing, because you wrote "Its working with all devices". "Its working with all devices" does not match "not working properly". So, what are you seeing? Is your app crashing? If so, use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with the crash.